# Extending WPF Calendar to support selecting many dates at once

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, selecteditem

I want to add a method to the WPF `Calendar` control to enable it to select many dates at once, and raise the `SelectedDatesChangedEvent` only once at the end.

The WPF `Calendar` control allows you to add only one date at a time (ranges are not useful to me). However I might need to add some 1000 dates and I don't want the `SelectedDatesChangedEvent` handler called 1000 times because in my case it's an expensive operation.

The WPF `DataGrid` has a very nice feature that allows for this to be done:

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public void ClearAndSelectMany(IEnumerable<DateTime> datesToBeSelected)
    {
        this.BeginUpdateSelectedItems();
        ...
        foreach (DateTime date in datesToBeSelected)
            this.SelectedDates.Add(date);
        ...
        this.EndUpdateSelectedItems();
    }
}
```

However the `Calendar` doesn't have anything like `DataGrid`'s `BeginUpdateSelectedItems()`, so I'm trying to create a workaround by preventing `base.OnSelectedDatesChanged()` being called until it's all done:

```
public class MyCalendar : Calendar
{
    protected override void OnSelectedDatesChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (false == this.temporaryDontReportSelectionChanged)
            base.OnSelectedDatesChanged(e); // this is where I get an exception
    }

    public void ClearAndSelectMany(IEnumerable<DateTime> datesToBeSelected)
    {
        this.temporaryDontReportSelectionChanged = true;
        ...
        foreach (DateTime date in datesToBeSelected)
            SelectedDates.Add(date);
        ...
        this.temporaryDontReportSelectionChanged = false;
        OnSelectedDatesChanged(
            new SelectionChangedEventArgs(
                MyCalendar.SelectedDatesChangedEvent,
                removedDates.ToList(),
                addedDates.ToList()));
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I'm getting an exception when calling `base.OnSelectedDatesChanged()`:

```
Unable to cast object of type
'System.EventHandler`1[System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs]'
to type
'System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler'.
```

I suppose I didn't properly create the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` object near the end, but I have no idea how to do it right. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update:** Motivated by Jamleck's question, I recreated the problem in a new project, and now have a bit more information to provide. Here's the `MyCalendar` class:

```
public class MyCalendar : System.Windows.Controls.Calendar
{
    private bool temporaryDontReportSelectionChanged;

    public MyCalendar()
    {
        // removing this line below makes my problem go away and it works ok
        this.SelectedDatesChanged += MyCalendar_SelectedDatesChanged;
    }

    void MyCalendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedDatesChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!temporaryDontReportSelectionChanged)
            base.OnSelectedDatesChanged(e);
    }

    public void ClearAndSelectMany(IEnumerable<DateTime> datesToBeSelected)
    {
        this.temporaryDontReportSelectionChanged = true;
        ...
        foreach (DateTime date in datesToBeSelected)
            SelectedDates.Add(date);
        ...
        this.temporaryDontReportSelectionChanged = false;
        OnSelectedDatesChanged(
            new SelectionChangedEventArgs(
                MyCalendar.SelectedDatesChangedEvent,
                removedDates.ToList(),
                addedDates.ToList()));
    }
}
```

So if I don't add an event handler to the `SelectedDatesChanged` event handler, everything works great, but if I do add it, then I get the `InvalidCastException` described above.

Comment: What version of .Net are you targeting? I run your code and didn't get any issues with multiple date selection.

Comment: Thanks @Jamleck for checking it out, I'm on .Net 4.5, Visual Studio 2013 Update 1, but I don't think that's the problem, I just updated the question above with a bit more information.